# Flask: How to use app context inside blueprints?

Tags: design-patterns, flask

I'm learning flask and python and cannot wrap my head around the way a typical flask application needs to be structured.

I need to access the app config from inside blueprint. Something like this

```
#blueprint.py
from flask import Blueprint

sample_blueprint = Blueprint("sample", __name__)

# defining a route for this blueprint
@sample_blueprint.route("/")
def index():
     # !this is the problematic line
     # need to access some config from the app
     x = app.config["SOMETHING"]
     # how to access app inside blueprint?
```

If importing app in blueprint is the solution, will this not result in circulat imports? i.e importing blueprint in app, importing app in blueprints?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the docs about [appcontext](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/appcontext/):

> The application context is what powers the **current_app** context local

Applied to your example:

```
from flask import Blueprint, current_app

sample = Blueprint('sample', __name__)

@sample.route('/')
def index():
    x = current_app.config['SOMETHING']
```

For reference here is a small [gist](https://gist.github.com/rtzll/8f0f7668c4ca9813e9380b45b932e7c2) I put together, as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: im not able to use current_app since it says there is no application context. Maybe I'm not getting this right. I will try to see if it is possible to do it the way you have mentioned.

Comment: if we split the blueprint to a seperate file, current_app is not working for me in the Blueprint. For me, blueprint has to be in a seperate file and the app in a seperate file.

Comment: the gist gives me a 404

Comment: The above code results in `RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.`. To fix I had to wrap the code accessing the config in the following: `with current_app.app_context:`

Answer (score 3):

In your app - when registering the blueprint - you need to push the context manually.

Refer to the snippet below and notice how the call-out to the init_db function is wrapped with the application context - the with ensures that the context is destroyed upon completion of your task.

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    with app.app_context():
        init_db()

    return app
```

[Source](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/appcontext/#creating-an-application-context)