# Getting flask-restful routes from within a blueprint

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

Is there a way to get the routes defined in a blueprint? I know this (http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/117/) snippit exists, but requires to have the app initalized to use url_map. Is there a way to view the routes without an application? I'm developing an api with flask-restful and I would like to display the routes from within the blueprint without the app to keep it self contained.

Comment: To get to the URLs the app has to be running. To access it from within the blueprint you can do `from flask import current_app` and use the snippet you referenced, by replacing `app` with `current_app`.

Comment: Maybe this answer helps as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39769666/flask-how-to-use-app-context-inside-blueprints/39777428#39777428

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the information provided by polyfunc, I was able to come up with this solution:

```
from flask import Blueprint, current_app, url_for
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

api_blueprint = Blueprint('api', __name__)
api = Api(api_blueprint)

@api.resource('/foo')
class Foo(Resource):
    def get(self):
        prefix = api_blueprint.name + '.'  # registered classes will have this as their prefix

        # Get current rules
        rules = current_app.url_map.iter_rules()

        # Get list from routes registered under the blueprint
        routes = [url_for(rule.endpoint) for rule in rules if rule.endpoint.startswith(prefix)]
```